# Why is there coming up the SyntaxError with if and elif[

Tags: python

I am trying to make a quiz in python. But the prizes cause errors.

I tried deleting the red spot but it changed location.

```
if (raha <= 1000):
    webbrowser.open('http://www.rrrgggbbb.com')

elif (2500 >= raha = > 1000):
    webbrowser.open('https://codepen.io/akm2/full/rHIsa')

elif (3000 >= raha = > 2500):
    webbrowser.open('https://turbo.fish/')

elif (4000 >= raha = > 4500):
    webbrowser.open('https://turbo.fish/')

elif (3000 >= raha = > 4000):
    webbrowser.open('https://hooooooooo.com/')

elif (4500 >= raha = > 6000):
    webbrowser.open('https://trypap.com/')

elif (6000 >= raha = > 8000):
    webbrowser.open('https://chrismckenzie.com/')

elif (8000 <= raha):
    print("sa võid auhinna ise valida. Keri alla")
    time.sleep(2)
    webbrowser.open('https://makefrontendshitagain.party/')
```

it should not say bad file descriptor

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: It should be `>=`, not `=>`

Comment: => operator seems to be invalid in python.

Comment: @umn I just realized that the edit is a bit "destructive", but since this was a typo and the question should be closed, it probably doesn't matter anyways.

Comment: Check out Python coding guidelines, in particular concerning formatting. Also note that Python's `if` doesn't require brackets, so remove those as well. Further, when you have problems with code, you first have to extract a [mcve] and include that in your question. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

The error is in comparison, not in if-elif. It has to be `>=` or `<=`. `=>` and `=<` are invalid. In some places, you have also put a space between `=` and `>`. So, `>=` is valid but `> ="` is not.

Use this:

```py
if raha <= 1000:
    webbrowser.open('http://www.rrrgggbbb.com')

elif 2500 >= raha >= 1000:
    webbrowser.open('https://codepen.io/akm2/full/rHIsa')

elif 3000 >= raha >= 2500:
    webbrowser.open('https://turbo.fish/')

elif 4000 >= raha >=  4500:
    webbrowser.open('https://turbo.fish/')

elif 3000 >= raha >=  4000:
    webbrowser.open('https://hooooooooo.com/')

elif 4500 >= raha >=  6000:
    webbrowser.open('https://trypap.com/')

elif 6000 >= raha >=  8000:
    webbrowser.open('https://chrismckenzie.com/')

elif 8000 <= raha:
    print("sa võid auhinna ise valida. Keri alla")
    time.sleep(2)
    webbrowser.open('https://makefrontendshitagain.party/')
```